# App force closing on button click?

Tags: java, android

A user may enter an alarm event to happen at a certain time. I have a button that calls all events and displays the time the event will happen. Every time i press on the button even when i set an event before hand, the app force closes. The Logcat points out 3 lines and i have no idea why.

Here is the logcat:

```
03-11 16:23:15.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13960): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 16:23:15.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13960):    at izzy.n.main1.getLastThreeEvents(main1.java:218)
03-11 16:23:15.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13960):    at izzy.n.main1.access$4(main1.java:192)
03-11 16:23:15.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13960):    at izzy.n.main1$4.onClick(main1.java:101)
03-11 16:23:15.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13960):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 16:23:15.101: E/AndroidRuntime(13960):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
```

Here is main1.java I put a link so you can see where each line of code is. http://codepad.org/7z3Vxq72

And here is main1.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_calendar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:text="Add Event"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_add2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:text="Add Event 2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_get_events"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:text="Get Events"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/text_event"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        />
</LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize `m_text_event` anywhere. Normally you would do it in `onCreate`, but I don't see a `TextView` in your layout.

Comment: You need to add something like this: `m_text_event = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview));`. Problem is, you don't have a `TextView` specified in your layout file.

Comment: @user1248404 - Did you assign a value to `m_text_event` in `onCreate` like Niek suggested?